# Two processes want to access same python file

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a scenario like Process1 and Process2 want to access same python file(sample.py). With respect to each process some code snippet is written. I don't want Process1 to access Process2 related python code and vice versa.

```
Process A
from myapp1 import ABC

Process B
from myapp2 import DEF
```

`from myapp1 import ABC` should not be accessible in Process B and `from myapp2 import DEF` should not be accessible in Process A

**Update:**

Fixed this issue by introducing environment variable in Process A and checking at sample.py.

Fix:
In manage.py(Process A) added `os.environ.setdefault("CS_DJANGO_MODULE", "1")`

In sample.py, added following code

```
CS_DJANGO = os.environ.get('CS_DJANGO_MODULE')
if CS_DJANGO == "1":
    from myapp1 import ABC
else:
    from myapp2 import DEF
```

Comment: Is there a reason against creating two different python scripts?

Comment: if you won't import a particular class or method in a program, that program will not have access to it.

Comment: @FlyingTeller - ProcessA is web app and Process B is custom app. But both of them accessing one file as part of lib

Comment: This is too broad, and perhaps a XY question. I suggest you post  minimal `sample.py` and process A and B python files, so we can better understand what you want to do (and why).